# add value and insert into setText

Tags: java, android

Hello I am creating a game and it has scores I need to make the points are added and changed with setText.

I am having trouble converting because I get the text value in string and summing it is giving error.

```
    TextView pvoce = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pvoce);
        TextView papp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.papp);

if (escolhaApp == "pedra" && escolhaUsuario == "tesoura" || escolhaApp == "papel" && escolhaUsuario == "pedra" || escolhaApp == "tesoura" && escolhaUsuario == "papel") {
            textoResultado.setText("    You Lose   ");
            String soma = 1;
            int totalapp = (soma + papp);
            String totalappString = Integer.toString(totalapp);
            papp.setText(totalappString);

        } else if (escolhaUsuario == "pedra" && escolhaApp == "tesoura" || escolhaUsuario == "papel" && escolhaApp == "pedra" || escolhaUsuario == "tesoura" && escolhaApp == "papel") {
            textoResultado.setText("   You Win   ");
            int soma = 1;
            int totalvoce = soma + pvoce;
            String totalvoceString = Integer.toString(totalvoce);
            pvoce.setText(totalvoceString);
        }
```

error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
first type:  int
second type: TextView

Comment: int totalapp = (soma + papp); 
this line error as papp is type of Textview and soma is String
int totalapp = (soma + papp.getText());
papp.getText() convert this t0 int

Same for 
int totalvoce = soma + pvoce;
pvoce is TextView and soma is Int
pvote.getText() convert this to int

Comment: int totalapp = (soma + Integer.parseInt(papp.getText()));

int totalvoce = soma + Integer.parseInt(pvoce.getText());

Comment: error: incompatible types: CharSequence cannot be converted to String in line updated

Comment: papp.getText().toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't have much stress on errors as it's already covered by previous answers. But here you may find the correct solution by commenting out your line of codes that have problems with some explanation of the issues, and writing directly below of each line the corrected code

```
TextView pvoce = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pvoce);
TextView papp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.papp);

if (escolhaApp == "pedra" && escolhaUsuario == "tesoura" || escolhaApp == "papel" && escolhaUsuario == "pedra" || escolhaApp == "tesoura" && escolhaUsuario == "papel") {
            textoResultado.setText("    You Lose   ");
            // String soma = 1; // wrong as java is statically typed language, you can't assign a int into a String 
            int soma = 1;

           //  int totalapp = (soma + papp); // papp is of TextView type, you need to get its text by getText(), convert it to String by .toString(), and then into int to make the integer addition valid
            int totalapp = soma + Integer.parseInt(papp.getText().toString());

            String totalappString = Integer.toString(totalapp);
            papp.setText(totalappString);

        } else if (escolhaUsuario == "pedra" && escolhaApp == "tesoura" || escolhaUsuario == "papel" && escolhaApp == "pedra" || escolhaUsuario == "tesoura" && escolhaApp == "papel") {
            textoResultado.setText("   You Win   ");
            int soma = 1;
           //  int totalvoce = soma + pvoce; // pvoce is of TextView type, you need to get its text by getText(), convert it to String by .toString(), and then into int to make the integer addition valid
            int totalvoce = soma + Integer.parseInt(pvoce.getText().toString());

            String totalvoceString = Integer.toString(totalvoce);
            pvoce.setText(totalvoceString);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java is a statically typed language which means you cannot assign values to incompatible types (`String soma = 1;` is not a valid assignment). Furthermore `papp` is an instance of `TextView` and not an `int`, so you cannot do `int totalapp = (soma + papp);`.

You would have to coerce the `TextView` text to an `int` before adding it to any other value, for example:

```
TextView papp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.papp);

int soma = 1;
int pappInt = 0;
try {
    pappInt = Integer.parseInt(papp.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // Cannot parse papp.getText() as an Integer
}

int totalapp = (soma + pappInt);
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: CharSequence cannot be converted to String
 in " pappInt = Integer.parseInt(papp.getText());"

Comment: `papp.getText().toString()`

Comment: m0skit0, I believe this converts papp to string and doesn't let it add up.

Comment: @RichardNicson I have edited my answer, it should work now.

Comment: Adding toString Error error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
first type:  int
second type: TextView

Comment: I need to get papp and add + 1 after that insert with setText

Comment: Thanks for your answer,To solve I did it:String pontoapp = papp.getText().toString();
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(pontoapp);
            int resultapp = (num1 + 1);
            papp.setText(String.valueOf(resultapp));

Answer (score 1):

Well , You have to revise java basics a little bit

```
        String soma = 1; // you have a problem here call it Problem 1 
        int totalapp = (soma + papp); //  because of Problem 1 you get part of  Problem 2  and because of  papp is a view object, not a value you get the second part  so you have to get it's valued first by getText() Method 



        String totalappString = Integer.toString(totalapp); // and Problem 3 here 
        papp.setText(totalappString);
```

Problem one is assignment problem String should be between ""

```
              String soma ="1"; 
or you can consider soma as int from the beginning.It depends on how you are solving the problem, let us just take care of the syntax errors and semantics are upon your logic.
```

Problem two is conversion problem since papp is a view containing String type the value should be obtained by getText() and then  be converted to Integer then used in summation

```
              int totalapp = (Integer.parseInt(soma) + 
              Integer.parseInt(papp.getText()));//note papp.getText()
```

Comment: I need to get papp and add + 1 after that insert with setText

Comment: Then you have to get the value first and convert 
something like this

`papp.setText( ( Integer.parseInt(soma.getText())+Integer.parseInt (papp.getText())+1) `

Comment: Thanks for your answer,To solve I did it:String pontoapp = papp.getText().toString();
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(pontoapp);
            int resultapp = (num1 + 1);
            papp.setText(String.valueOf(resultapp));